How to fix "tuned" errors for KVM set up?
I am following this video on setting up KVM. On the part setting up tuned, I am encountering this problem. How do I fix these errors?
$ sudo tuned-adm profile virtual-host
$ tuned-adm active
Current active profile: virtual-host
$ sudo tuned-adm verify
    Verification failed, current system settings differ from the preset profile.
    You can mostly fix this by restarting the Tuned daemon, e.g.:
      systemctl restart tuned
    or
      service tuned restart
    Sometimes (if some plugins like bootloader are used) a reboot may be required.
    See tuned log file ('/var/log/tuned/tuned.log') for details.

Errors in '/var/log/tuned/tuned.log'
2024-05-12 23:24:17,197 ERROR    tuned.utils.commands: Executing modprobe error: modprobe: FATAL: Module cpufreq_conservative is builtin.
2024-05-12 23:24:17,203 ERROR    tuned.utils.commands: Error when reading file '/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method': '[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method''
2024-05-12 23:24:17,203 WARNING  tuned.plugins.plugin_video: radeon_powersave is not supported on 'card0'

2024-05-12 23:54:53,832 ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist
2024-05-12 23:54:53,832 ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.
2024-05-12 23:54:53,832 ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist
2024-05-12 23:54:53,832 ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.
2024-05-12 23:54:53,833 ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns', the parameter does not exist
2024-05-12 23:54:53,833 ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.

